# Condescending comments and answers

Tags: discussion, comments, review

This question in particular

[Can you request a new squawk code if you don’t like the one being assigned?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/81546/can-you-request-a-new-squawk-code-if-you-don-t-like-the-one-being-assigned)

It seems that the person's superstition and belief is being questioned and answer more than the answer. Can the comments and answers be cleaned up to just address the question?

It easily could have been asked as "Can ATC change a squawk code on request?"

And the first answer, which the first paragraph answers the question could be "no, most assignments are automated and it'd increase the workload, etc etc"

And I think a generic answer like that is

1. more useful in the future since it can answer generically for other questions like "can they squawk my birthday on my birthday"
2. doesn't show hostility to users who find the question and may be new to the stack

Answer (score 6):

Please always flag any comments as "Rude or abusive" that you feel is even close to the line of being rude or unwelcoming. These will be dealt with swiftly, comments are not for this kind of thing - once again they should only be used to clarify or improve questions/answers.

If you find the tone of an answer to be condescending you are free to suggest edits and there is no reason for that edit to not be taken if it improves the friendliness/futureproofing of the answer.

If an answer is just wrong you can downvote as appropriate.

Edit: I've also had a tidy up of the comments there - thanks for bringing attention. Anything you feel I've missed please flag as above.

Comment: Thanks! It seemed a lot to flag all at once. Good question and answer overall so I didn't want to see it get deleted.

Comment: @Bageletas you could also consider flagging the question or answer (wherever you see rudeness or unwelcoming language) with a custom flag explaining what you think the problem is.